# unable to load login page over public ip

Tags: networking, server, apache2, ssl, tomcat6

I have a page to load as https://218.251.240.118:8080/login ... but I am getting ssl connection error. Below are the configuration file details :

apache httpd.conf file (since the file was big I am posting only uncommented lines)

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache22-publisher"
Listen 80
User apache
Group apache
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ServerName pro-pcrawler101d:80
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache22-publisher/htdocs"

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>


<Directory "/data/publisher_files">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

Alias /icons/ "/data/icons/"

<Directory "/data/icons">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/data/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/data/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /error/ "/data/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
<Directory "/data/error">
AllowOverride None
Options IncludesNoExec
AddOutputFilter Includes html
AddHandler type-map var
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
LanguagePriority en es de fr
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

ServerSignature Off
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
Alias /publisher /data/publisher_files
Alias /rcr /data/publisher_files
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

here is my httpd-ssl.conf file (since the file was big I am posting only uncommented lines):

```
Listen 443
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl 
SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/usr/local/apache22-      publisher/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
SSLMutex "file:/usr/local/apache22-publisher/logs/ssl_mutex"
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/data/publisher_files"

ServerName pro-pcrawler101zd:443
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/usr/local/apache22-publisher/logs/error_log"
TransferLog "/usr/local/apache22-publisher/logs/access_log"

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache22-publisher/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache22-publisher/conf/server.key"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/usr/local/apache22-publisher/cgi-bin">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "/usr/local/apache22-publisher/logs/ssl_request_log" \
"t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x "%r" %b"

ProxyPass /rcr ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/rcr
ProxyPassReverse /rcr ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/rcr

</VirtualHost>
```

Tried restarting tomcat and httpd service, no changes.tomcat and httpd are running and listening on respective ports.Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I see a few issues (but it could just be your extracted sections), in your http.conf, your ifmodule sections appear unbalanced.

Comment: How are you mapping your port 8080 to internal 443?  Can you connect locally?  Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Hi progrock, there is nothing in the logs. I dont know how 8080 is getting mapped, tomcat is something new for me.

Comment: this is what im getting internally

[ ~]# wget https://10.40.5.32:8080/login
--2015-12-07 11:48:04--  https://10.40.5.32:8080/login
Connecting to 10.40.5.32:8080... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

What SSL connection error are you getting?

Things to check:

- Is you TLS/SSL cert signed by a CA that you trust in the browser that you are trying to pull it up on?
- Does the cert have the ip address as the cn or a subjectAltName?
- I don't see a CA bundle. Do you have a cert bundle that has all the intermediate/CA certs that are needed for your cert?

Comment: please lemme know how can I check these things

Comment: this is what im getting internally [ ~]# wget 10.40.5.32:8080/login --2015-12-07 11:48:04-- 10.40.5.32:8080/login Connecting to 10.40.5.32:8080... connected. Unable to establish SSL connection. –

Comment: openssl verify /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem: /C=US/O=RSA Data Security, Inc./OU=Secure Server Certification Authority
error 10 at 0 depth lookup:certificate has expired
OK

Comment: So you found that it was expired?